# ConcurrentHashMap as cache performance

Tags: java, spring, performance, caching, join

I am using spring 4, I have create the following class for cache to avoid the joins

```
package com.pu.services;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class CacheSRV {

private Map<Long, String> countriesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();
private Map<Long, String> provinceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();
private Map<Long, String> divisionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();
private Map<Long, String> districtMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();
private Map<Long, String> cityMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();
private Map<Long, String> zoneMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();

public Map<Long, String> getCountriesMap() {
    return countriesMap;
}

public void setCountriesMap(Map<Long, String> countriesMap) {
    this.countriesMap = countriesMap;
}

public Map<Long, String> getProvinceMap() {
    return provinceMap;
}

public void setProvinceMap(Map<Long, String> provinceMap) {
    this.provinceMap = provinceMap;
}

public Map<Long, String> getDivisionMap() {
    return divisionMap;
}

public void setDivisionMap(Map<Long, String> divisionMap) {
    this.divisionMap = divisionMap;
}

public Map<Long, String> getDistrictMap() {
    return districtMap;
}

public void setDistrictMap(Map<Long, String> districtMap) {
    this.districtMap = districtMap;
}

public Map<Long, String> getCityMap() {
    return cityMap;
}

public void setCityMap(Map<Long, String> cityMap) {
    this.cityMap = cityMap;
}

public Map<Long, String> getZoneMap() {
    return zoneMap;
}

public void setZoneMap(Map<Long, String> zoneMap) {
    this.zoneMap = zoneMap;
}

}
```

when I get the value , it iterate all the map to find out the value . 
Suppose, I get a list of Student, the list size of student is 100 and there are 195 countries in the world. so , its means for every iteration , I need to iterate 195 countries to find out the country belong to student. is that performance overhead? if yes ,how to overcome ?

or I its better to use join

```
Select * from  Student ST
INNER JOIN COUNTRY C ON C.countryid = st.countryid
INNER JOIN Province P ON P.provinceid = st.provinceid 
INNER JOIN Division D ON D.divisionid = st.divisionid 
INNER JOIN District DS ON DS.districtid = st.districtid 
INNER JOIN City CT ON CT.cityid = st.cityid 
INNER JOIN Zone ZE ON ZE.zoneid = st.zoneid
```

Answer (score 2):

> there are 195 countries in the world. so , its means for every iteration , I need to iterate 195 countries to find out the country belong to student.

WAT? Didn't you want to use a `Map`?

```
countriesMap.get(student.countryId)
```

and you're done. It's (apart from rare problems with excessive collisions) a constant time operation.

While databases are damn good at joining, using maps will surely be faster. However, it has other disadvantages:

- In case of changing data, you'd need to keep your in sync with your table. This may get pretty complicated.
- Your maps are limited by the physical memory you have, while your tables may get orders of magnitude bigger.

Both should be no problem in your case. The question if it's worth doing remains.

Comment: Yes I am using `countriesMap.get(student.countryId)`, will it not iterate until find the value ? will get value directly using key without iteration?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor Sure, that's how the `HashMap` works. Its speed is practically independent of its size. http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/hashing-how-hash-map-works-in-java-or.html